# Different length of error bars in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a graph with different errors each point, independent of the value.

My code is here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y=[10,20,30,40,50,60] 
errorx=[0.1,0.3,0.7,0.6,1,1.5,0.2] 
errory=[0.1,0.8,0.4,2.3,0.1,1.2,0.6] 
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=None,xerr=None) 
plt.plot(x,y)
```

I don't get what I want; I want without the line connecting the dots and the x and y-error bar

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You are more likely to get an answer if you show us what you have done so far. A good start would be to look at the matplotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/).

Comment: Put your code into the question and format it correctly. If you put yerr=None, then there won't be any errorbar. Look at [this example](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html) to find out how to use this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you set `yerr` and `xerr` equal to `None` in your example (as seen in your comment), therefore no error bars will be shown. Secondly, your list of x and y errors are not the same length as that of your x and y coordinates. Therefore if you tried to plot this you would get a `ValueError: xerr must be a scalar, the same dimensions as x, or 2xN.` and the same thing would happen for your the y error too. The errorbar documentation can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar).

A working example using your data is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [10,20,30,40,50,60]

errorx = [0.1,0.3,0.7,0.6,1,1.5]  #now the same length as x and y
errory = [0.1,0.8,0.4,2.3,0.1,1.2]

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=errory, xerr=errorx, linestyle='') 
#change linestyle to not connect the points

plt.show()
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]